# Pass elements between C# and JavaScript

Tags: c#, .net, webkit, webbrowser-control, webkit.net

I'm in the process of replacing a .NET's `WebBrowser` for a `WebKit.NET`, and one of the functionalities I've been using in the `WebBrowser` that I can't figure out how to implement in the wrapper I'm writing around `WebKit` is the ability to pass DOM elements from and to JavaScript and C# code.

In a `WebBrowser` you'd just call [`InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript.aspx) and pass an the [`DomElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.domelement.aspx) property of an `HtmlElement` as a parameter, and the JavaScript function would get the element. Same way, you can pass an element from JavaScript to C# and the C# code would get a `DomElement` object.

In `WebKit` as far as I know I cannot do this. The `InvokeStriptMethod` method is broken, but the `StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is not, which let me inject scripts into the current document and invoke them any time later.

Note that these documents won't be my own created documents so I can't do stuff like assigning ID's to every element. This is a web scraper and I need to avoid messing with the document's elements as much as possible.

One hack that would probably work is assigning a temporary ID to the element and keeping the old ID backed up, then I can do a `GetElementById` call from either JavaScript or C# to get the element, and then reassign the old element's ID. The problem is that WebKit's `GetAttribute('id')` will give me an empty string when the ID is `undefined`, so there is no way for my C# code to know whether the ID was an empty string or `undefined`, and who knows, the current web page's script could rely on the ID being `undefined` for some reason, so setting the ID to an empty string could mess up their javascript.

Anyone has a better idea or is there any other `WebKit` method I could use?

Comment: Question is too ambiguous, add a code example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
and use this code

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(your_object, null, 2);
```

your object is now a string 
and you can do this to make your string an object

```
var your_object = JSON.parse(json_text);
```

you can pass your string from javascript to c sharp.

in csharp you can use fastjason and

```
var o = fastJSON.JSON.Instance.ToObject<List<Retclass>>(s); // return a generic list
```

and

```
string str = fastJSON.JSON.Instance.ToJSON(obj, 
                 new fastJSON.JSONParamters { EnableAnonymousTypes = true }); // using the parameters
```

You can do that using JSON

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange
>   format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for
>   machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the
>   JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition -
>   December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language
>   independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of
>   the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript,
>   Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal
>   data-interchange language.

http://www.json.org/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON

Comment: This answer is too ambiguous. How would you do that using JSON?

Comment: I guess it is not your fault, the question is too ambiguous.

Comment: I can't be especific if the question is not especific